# IE conditional stylesheet not loading

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have a [rails app](http://vols.herokuapp.com) ([source](https://github.com/OneAcreCafe/volunteers)) where I am trying to change fix some display bugs in Internet Explorer. In `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` I have:

```
/[if IE]                                                                                                                                                              
  = stylesheet_link_tag "ie", media: "all"
```

This seems to be generating the appropriate HTML with the precompiled asset which is downloadable from the server:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="/assets/ie-21dfbd4e306a3f4685597c40061f9d43.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

The contents of the stylesheet are simply:

```
#logo {
  display: none;
}
```

When the page is displayed in IE, however, the logo still appears.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing this with?

Comment: If you're using IE10 or above, this won't work.

Comment: As they say, ie10+ won't use conditional comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page in the Microsoft Developer Network Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28vs.85%29.aspx), conditional comments were first supported in Internet Explorer 5, and are no longer supported in Internet Explorer 10 and later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact not using IE10, do you have a second style sheet for non-IE browsers?  Is this before or after this conditional comment in your HTML?  If it is ***after*** and it contains `#logo { display: block; }` or similar its styles will override that of the IE specific CSS file.